# How to mock Google Guava cache builder?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, google-guava-cache

```
    @Component
    public class LibraryService {

        @Autowired
        private BookService bookService;

        private Cache<UUID, Book> bookCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(512).expireAfterWrite(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();

        public void someMethod(UUID bookId) {
          try {
            Book book = bookCache.get(bookId, () -> bookService.findBookByUuid(bookId));
            //some operations
          } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new ProcessingFailureException("Failed to load cache value", e);
          }

         }

    }
```

I need to write unit test for this class so that I tried to mock the Google Guava cache as following.

```
public class LibraryServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private LibraryService service;

    @Mock
    private BookService bookService;

    @Mock
    private Cache<UUID, Book> bookCache;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws ExecutionException {
        UUID bookId = UUID.randomUUID();
        Book book = new Book();

        when(bookCache.get(bookId, () -> bookService.findBookByUuid(bookId))).thenReturn(book);

        service.someMethod(bookId);
    }
}
```

I got some NullPointer Exception.

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2203)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4739)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Note: I know, I can change the method some testable way. In this case I couldn't do that.

Is there any way to mock this book cache?

Comment: Does `@InjectMocks` overwrite random, already assigned, private variables? You need to be thinking in more IoC terms - a `Cache` is a **dependency** of `LibraryService` - it should therefore be interfaced away and injected in. In fact, as you are using Spring, may I suggest [Spring Cache](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) - supports Guava `Cache` as a backend so functionally your code would be the same.

Comment: Yeah, I understand but thing is I couldn't change the implementation at this moment.

Comment: Could you not test that `BookService` is not called again for a second attempt to load a supposedly cached book? The way this class is written, `Cache` is a private implementation detail and should not be tested. The expected behaviour should be. See also [`Ticker`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#testing-timed-eviction) - but if you cannot change any code you are out of luck on that front too.

Comment: yeah, I think so. I could skip unit testing for this method and later change it and write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work if you better mock the `get` method call as next to ensure arguments match such that you will get the expected book instance as result.

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
...

public class LibraryServiceTest {
    ...

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws ExecutionException {
        ...
        when(bookCache.get(eq(bookId), any(Callable.class))).thenReturn(book);
        ...
    }
}
```